# Weird icons border in footer in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, border, footer

I'm working on a web in Wordpress and I have some trouble with the footer. I have three widgets and in the middle one I want to put some social icons. I have tried with different plugins and the problem is the same: first icon shows great but next are showing a weird border and I have no idea how to modify.

[image]

Could someone pitch in?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be a css style issue. If the first icon looks right, maybe the styles only apply to the first because the icon html elements aren't having the same class or the css selector is wrong (something like `icon-class:first-child`).

I would check your Browser Dev Tools:

- Check if the icon html elements are all having the same class.
- If they do, maybe the icon file itself is just ugly. You can check the file in the dev tools by hovering the file URL. If that is the case, the plugin provider should updates the icons.
- If the don't have the same css class, you should customize your css, maybe there is a way in the widget plugin.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I followed your suggestions but the icon elements have the same class and I think it's not a problem of the plugin because other plugins make the same mistake. I tried to customize my css but I'm not able to find the mistake